# Ansible Host_vars and groups for inventory file

Tags: ansible

I am using 3 machines, one for Ansible Master (Centos), Another one is Ansible target1 (Centos), the Last one is Ansible Node2 (windows10).

Here I am having simply an inventory file with all the details

```
target1 ansible_host=192.168.0.2 ansible_ssh_pass="{{ans_pass}}" ansible_ssh_user="{{ans_user}}"
win ansible_host=192.168.0.3 ansible_password="{{ans_pass}}" ansible_connection=winrm ansible_port=5986 ansible_user="{{ans_user}}" ansi                                                      ble_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

Next, I created two directories namely groups_vars and host_vars.

groups_vars/secret.yaml file contains below values which are declared in the inventory file

```
ans_user: username
ans_pass: pwd
```

Another file host_vars/secret.yaml which contains login information about windows configuration data

```
ans_user: username
ans_pass: pwd
```

When I am doing the ping test from my ansible master machine I am getting below error, can you please someone help me out to fix this issue.

Error

```
target1 | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The field 'remote_user' has an invalid value, which includes an undefined variable.
The error was: 'ans_user' is undefined"
}
```

After the discussion with Vladimir Botka, I am updating post.

```
[root@master Ansible]# tree group_vars/
group_vars/
├── groups_vars_playbook.yaml
└── secret.yaml

0 directories, 2 files

ssh: Could not resolve hostname target1: Name or service not known
```

Comment: group**s**_vars => group_vars https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**: The names of the files in the directories *group_vars* and *host_vars* must correspond to the names of the groups and hosts respectively. *host_vars* override *group_vars*.

**Details**: Quoting from [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables)

> *"If your inventory file at /etc/ansible/hosts contains a host named ‘foosball’ that belongs to two groups, ‘raleigh’ and ‘webservers’, that host will use variables in YAML files at the following locations:"*

```
/etc/ansible/group_vars/raleigh # can optionally end in '.yml', '.yaml', or '.json'
/etc/ansible/group_vars/webservers
/etc/ansible/host_vars/foosball
```

---

**group_vars**

The hosts in the inventory below do not belong to any group. Therefore the variables in *group_vars/secret.yaml* won't be used

```
shell> cat hosts
target1
win`
```

The variables in *group_vars/secret.yaml* will be used when the hosts belong to the group *secret*, e.g. see below

```
shell> cat hosts
[secret]
target1
win`
```

For example, the playbook and group_vars below

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yaml
- hosts: secret
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ans_user
    - debug:
        var: ans_pass

shell> cat group_vars/secret.yaml
ans_user: group_username
ans_pass: group_pwd
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yaml

ok: [target1] => 
  ans_user: group_username
ok: [win] => 
  ans_user: group_username

ok: [target1] => 
  ans_pass: group_pwd
ok: [win] => 
  ans_pass: group_pwd
```

---

**host_vars**

There is no host *secret*. Therefore the file *host_vars/secret.yaml* won't be used. There are host *target1* and *win* only. Host's specific variables will be read from the files *host_vars/target1.yaml* and *host_vars/win.yaml* respectively. For example, the same inventory, playbook, and group_vars with additional host_vars below

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/target1.yaml
ans_user: target1_username
ans_pass: target1_pwd

shell> cat host_vars/win.yaml
ans_user: win_username
ans_pass: win_pwd
```

give (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts playbook.yaml

ok: [win] => 
  ans_user: win_username
ok: [target1] => 
  ans_user: target1_username

ok: [win] => 
  ans_pass: win_pwd
ok: [target1] => 
  ans_pass: target1_pwd
```

The variables from the files in the directory *host_vars* will [override](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) the variables from the files in the directory *group_vars*.

Comment: Hi Botka,

thanks for the quick reply based on your instruction I just updated my /etc/ansible/hosts file and group_var/secret.YAML file, but now I am getting unable to reach target host1, I updated error log above.